# Lodash find by key and mergeWith while preserving specific key value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I have 2 collections, the "parent" and the "child" collection.

I need to:

- Find child items in the parent by ctaTypeNameUID
- The parent object should be overwritten by the child object if the child object values are not null.
- keep the order of the child
- keep just the parent items that exist on the child + custom ones from child

**Parent Object**

```
"parentObjectOverrideable": [{
    "cta_type": {
      "title": null,
      "ctaTypeNameUID": "enjoy-new-york",
      "form-url": "F-2009",
      "city": "New York",
      "address": null
    }
  },
  {
    "cta_type": {
      "title": null,
      "ctaTypeNameUID": "enjoy-london",
      "form-url": "F-2010",
      "city": "London",
      "address": null
    }
  }

]
```

**Child Object**

```
"childObject": [{
    "cta_type": {
      "title": "Enjoy London",
      "ctaTypeNameUID": "enjoy-london",
      "form-url": "F-2009",
      "city": null,
      "address": null
    }
  },
  {
    "cta_type": {
      "title": "Enjoy New York",
      "ctaTypeNameUID": "enjoy-new-york",
      "form-url": "F-22827166628",
      "city": null,
      "address": null
    }
  },
]
```

I have tried using _mergeWith from Lodash

```
const result = _.mergeWith([], parentObjectOverrideable, childObject, (a, b) =>
  b === null || b === '' ? a : undefined
)
```

the problem is that if the position of the cta_type is different on the child object, it overrides the UID as well so you get something like this:

```
"parentObjectOverrideable": [{
    "cta_type": {
      "title": "Enjoy London",
      ,
      "ctaTypeNameUID": "enjoy-new-york",
      "form-url": "F-2009"
      "city": null "address": null
    }
  },
  {
    "cta_type": {
      "title": "Enjoy New York",
      "ctaTypeNameUID": "enjoy-london",
      "form-url": "F-2010",
      "city": null,
      "address": null
    }
  }

]
```

I have tried to do this as well

```
const overrideObject = (objA, objB) => {
  const newObject = { ...objB
  }

  Object.keys(objA).forEach((key) => {
    if (objA[key]) {
      newObject[key] = objA[key]
    }
  })

  console.log(newObject)
}
```

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concat the items to a single array, group it `cta_type.ctaTypeNameUID`, and the merge each group to a single object, letting `_.mergeBy()` handle merging objects and arrays, and handling primitives by using `a` unless it's `null`, and `b` is not `undefined`.

```js
const { flow, concat, groupBy, flatMap, mergeWith, isObject, isUndefined, isNull, intersectionBy } = _

const fn = flow(
  concat,
  arr => groupBy(arr, 'cta_type.ctaTypeNameUID'),
  groups => flatMap(groups, group => mergeWith({}, ...group, (a, b, k) => {
    if(isObject(a) || isObject(b)) return undefined

    return !isUndefined(b) && isNull(a) ? b : a
  })),
)

const parentObjectOverrideable = [{"cta_type":{"title":null,"ctaTypeNameUID":"enjoy-new-york","form-url":"F-2009","city":"New York","address":null}},{"cta_type":{"title":null,"ctaTypeNameUID":"enjoy-london","form-url":"F-2010","city":"London","address":null}}]
const childObject = [{"cta_type":{"title":"Enjoy London","ctaTypeNameUID":"enjoy-london","form-url":"F-2009","city":null,"address":null}},{"cta_type":{"title":"Enjoy New York","ctaTypeNameUID":"enjoy-new-york","form-url":"F-22827166628","city":null,"address":null}}]

const result = fn(
  childObject,
  intersectionBy(parentObjectOverrideable, childObject, 'cta_type.ctaTypeNameUID')
)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

With lodash/fp you can skip the intermediate values, and replace `_.mergeWith()` with `_.mergeAllWith()`, which handles arrays:

```js
const { flow, intersectionBy, concat, groupBy, flatMap, mergeAllWith, isObject, isUndefined, isNull } = _

const fn = flow(
  concat,
  groupBy('cta_type.ctaTypeNameUID'),
  flatMap(mergeAllWith((a, b) => {
    if(isObject(a) || isObject(b)) return undefined 

    return !isUndefined(b) && isNull(a) ? b : a
  }))
)

const parentObjectOverrideable = [{"cta_type":{"title":null,"ctaTypeNameUID":"enjoy-new-york","form-url":"F-2009","city":"New York","address":null}},{"cta_type":{"title":null,"ctaTypeNameUID":"enjoy-london","form-url":"F-2010","city":"London","address":null}}]
const childObject = [{"cta_type":{"title":"Enjoy London","ctaTypeNameUID":"enjoy-london","form-url":"F-2009","city":null,"address":null}},{"cta_type":{"title":"Enjoy New York","ctaTypeNameUID":"enjoy-new-york","form-url":"F-22827166628","city":null,"address":null}}]

const result = fn(
  childObject,
  intersectionBy('cta_type.ctaTypeNameUID', parentObjectOverrideable, childObject)
)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Wish I could pay you a beer haha. How do you preserve the order of the child object? I've went with the first option

Comment: The 1st array determines the order. You can change the order of the arrays you feed to the function, so children would be 1st, and reverse the logic in the merge to take the values from `a` as long as it's not `null`.

Comment: Sorry one more thing on top of all this - what if you want to store in the results just the objects that are in the child array?

Comment: After before you merge the two arrays, use `_.intersectionBy(child, parent, 'cta_type.ctaTypeNameUID')` to keep just the parent items that exist on the child.

Comment: I've tried like this but it doesn't give the parent items, just the child ones, if I revert it I just get the parent items, it looks like it doesn't even get merged if I run intersectionBy
`const result = fn(
  _.intersectionBy(parent, child, 'cta_type.ctaTypeNameUID')
 )`

Comment: Should I do it inside the body of the mergeWith function? 
`mergeWith({}, ...group, (a, b) => {
     if (isObject(a) || isObject(b)) return undefined
     return !isUndefined(b) && isNull(a) ? b : a
    })`

Comment: Updated both examples.

Comment: You're welcome. No need. It's a learning experience for me as well.

Comment: Cool! Wish you all the best, I've cleaned up the question a bit. I'm sure a lot of people will find this useful