# A lookup function to match the same IDs in two different arrays of objects and inserting key/value pairs into one of the array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 different arrays with objects. I want to be basically match an ID from both of the array of objects and then basically take the key value pair from the matching object and add it to the other array's object.

For example this is one of the array of objects

```
const groups = [{id: "1234"}, {id: "4321}]
```

The second array would look something like this

```
const childCategories = [{id: "4321", url:"/b/test"}, {id: "2223", url:"/b/test32"}]
```

So in this case since `childCategories.id = "4321"` matches with `groups.id = "4321"` it would add the `url: "/b/test"` to the matching ID's to the groups object so the result should be

```
const groups = [{id: "4321", url: "/b/test"}, {id: "1234}]
```

It should also only add the `url` key value pair to the `groups` object as there can be other properties that shouldn't be added to the `groups` object.

I have tried using `.find` but i don't think it's supported by IE11.

This is currently what I've currently tried and it's not quite working properly or probably the most efficient.

```
const getCategoryUrl = (childCategories, groups) => {
    groups.map(group => {
      const url = childCategories.find(child => child.id === group.id).url;
      childCategories.find(child => child.id === group.id) ? {...group, url} : group
    })
    return groups
}
```

Comment: you meant result should be `[{id: "4321", url: "/b/test"}, {id: "1234}]`?

Comment: You can check this question from today. It will help you a lot https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67214930/lodash-find-by-key-and-mergewith-while-preserving-specific-key-value#67215537

Comment: if you need to support IE11, use babel. You should first solve the problem, then worry about compatibility

Comment: Also, you should post what have you tried, show the code you created to try and solve this yourself

Comment: @iagowp thanks for the tips. I posted what I got so far on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was it able to get it working with this

```
const getCategory = (childCategories, groups) => {
    let matchGroup;
    groups.map(group => {
       matchGroup = childCategories.filter(child =>
        child.id === group.id ? {...group,url: child.url} : group
      )
    })
    return matchGroup
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this, without a find:

```
childCategories.forEach(cc => {
    groups.forEach(g =>{
        if(cc.id == g.id){
            g.url = cc.url;
        }
    });
```

This is, I should point out, pretty horribly inefficient, as it iterates through the groups collection completely for every object in childCategories.

With find it would look something like this:

```
childCategories.forEach(cc => {
    let matchGroup = groups.find(g =>{
        return g.id == cc.id;
    });
    if(matchGroup!=null) matchGroup.url = cc.url;
});
```

Comment: I might be able to use .find what would that look like with .find? If anything I can always use a polyfill or something too